# How to display complete message on Graylog?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat, graylog

I am trying to display complete log message which my java app creates on AKS.
Stack details-
Logging server: Graylog
Shipping logs: Filebeat
Platform: Azure Kubernetes

Below is my Filebeat configuration

```
filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: container
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.log
      "multiline": {
        multiline.pattern: '^[[:space:]]'
        multiline.negate: true
        multiline.match: after
        }
    - type: log
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.log
      "multiline": {
        multiline.pattern: '^[[:space:]]+(at|\.{3})[[:space:]]+\b|^Caused by:'
        multiline.negate: true
        multiline.match: after
        }
    - type:log
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.log
      "multiline": {
        multiline.pattern: 'Start new event'
        multiline.negate: true
        multiline.match: after
        multiline.flush_pattern: 'End event'
        }
    - type:log
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.log
      "multiline": {
        multiline.pattern: '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
        multiline.negate: true
        multiline.match: after
        }
```

I have tried to add many multiline patterns but the output of my logs comes with "... 6 common frames omitted". As shown below
[image]

Please let me know if am missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

That is not a filebeat "issue".

What is happening here, is tomcat electing to not show the entire stack trace.